# Build a string of HEX and strings. How?

Tags: c#

It turns out building the following string in python...

```
# global variables
cr = '\x0d' # segment terminator
lf = '\x0a' # data element separator
rs = '\x1e' # record separator
sp = '\x20' # white space

a = 'hello'
b = 'world'

output = a + rs + b
```

...is not the same as it may be in C#.

How do I accomplish the same in C#?

Comment: Can show the literal result you are looking for.

Comment: Strings in C# are enclosed in quotes, `"`.

Comment: I get the double quotes part. What I mean is, C# gives errors with you try to build a string of hex characters and normal strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you're trying to accomplish you can encapsulate that in a class.

```
public class StringStuff
{
    private const char cr = '\x0d'; // segment terminator
    private const char lf = '\x0a'; // data element separator
    private const char rs = '\x1e'; // record separator
    private const char sp = '\x20'; // white space

    public string BuildString()
    {
        var a = "hello";
        var b = "world";

        var output = a + rs + b

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you are trying to accomplish but try this:

```
// global variables
char cr = '\x0d'; // segment terminator
char lf = '\x0a'; // data element separator
char rs = '\x1e'; // record separator
char sp = '\x20'; // white space

string a = "hello";
string b = "world";

string output = a + rs + b;
```

You can also use **string** instead of **char** but then use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: Good lord. I think I was awake for too long last night converting python code to C# and started writing code outside of functions... Thanks a lot.